# How display flex affects on line-height of element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a strange behavior of display flex. In some cases it uses line-height of element and height depends on it, and in other cases it can be ignored and min-size of content inside is set.

For example for defined styles line-height will be ignored - height of element will be the same as size of svg

```
<div style="display:flex; line-height: 5">
  <div style="display: inline-flex; line-height: 10">
    <svg>...</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

If for outer div remove style `display:flex` then size of element will be the same as it's line-height 5

```
<div style="line-height: 5">
  <div style="display: inline-flex; line-height: 10">
    <svg>...</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

If for inner div remove style `display:inline-flex` then size of element will be the same as it's line-height 10

```
<div style="line-height: 5">
  <div style="line-height: 10">
    <svg>...</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone explain why it's working this way? It works as expected with text, and always applies line-height for text.

```css
svg {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
  line-height: 10;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 5;
}
```

```html
  <div class="block">
      <span class="inline">
       <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M11 7h2v2h-2zm0 4h2v6h-2z">
       </path><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z">
       </path>
       </svg>
      </span>
 </div>

<div class="block">
    <span class="inline">
      ------
    </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works as expected with text, and always applies line-height for text.

And you no more have text in your case when you apply `inline-flex` and `flex`. You deal with flex-level element and no more inline-level elements

> A flex item establishes an independent formatting context for its contents. However, flex items themselves are **flex-level boxes** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)</sup>

and

> The display value of a flex item is **blockified**: if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalen

So your example

```html
<div style="display:flex; line-height: 5">
  <!-- I am a flex items since my parent has display:flex and my inline-flex will get transformed to flex -->
  <div style="display: inline-flex; line-height: 10"> 
    <!-- I am a flex item since my parent is has display:inline-flex -->
    <svg>...</svg> 
  </div>
</div>
```

`line-height` will have no effect here since we have no inline-level elements and no IFC (inline formatting context)

> On a **block container element** whose content is composed of **inline-level elements,** 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.  <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height)</sup>

and

> On a non-replaced **inline element**, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

---

In the second example where you have text, the story is a bit different because you will have a flex item that will create an inline formating context for it's content.

> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous sequence of child text runs is wrapped in an **anonymous block container flex item**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)</sup>

So your text is wrapped inside a *hidden* block container and that block container will inherit the `line-height` and the logic of line-height will apply

Here is an illustration

```
<div class="block"> <!-- flexbox container -->
    <span class="inline"> <!-- flex item & flexbox container -->
      <anonymous> <!-- I am an anonymous block container created by the browser & a flex item and I will inherit the line-height  -->
        ------
      <anonymous>
    </span>
 </div>
```

---

With your SVG example, if you add a text the line-height will strike again:

```css
svg {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
  line-height: 10;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span class="inline">
       <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M11 7h2v2h-2zm0 4h2v6h-2z">
       </path><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z">
       </path>
       </svg> a
      </span>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <span class="inline">
      ------
    </span>
</div>
```

You will have 2 flex items, the SVG and an *anonymous block container flex item* for your text and this one will have the line-height applied to it.